# how to find S or less nodes in tree with minimum distance?

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, depth-first-search

Given a unweighted and undirected n-ary tree with N nodes and N-1 edges. Nodes are numbered from 0 to N-1. I need to find S or less nodes so as to get to each node at the smallest distance D. On first line in input is N (number of nodes) and S (maximum number of output nodes). On the next N-1 lines are description of edges. On output I have to write D, S´ (number of nodes, that I used) and marked 
nodes from S´. Example:
Input:

```
16 3
3 0
3 11
11 4
0 15
15 13
4 2
0 1
1 8
15 12
3 10
11 14
14 6
2 5
13 9
15 7
```

Output:

```
3 2
0
11
```

[image]

Other correct output:

```
3 3
5
6
15
```

[image]

I think I should use depth first search and count distance from nearest node from S and I should use binary search for search smallest D. But I have a problem with implementation in c++. For now I have code, that create tree, but I don´t know, how use depth first search in this case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

// data structure to store graph edges
struct Edge {
    int src, dest;
};

// class to represent a graph object
class Graph
{
public:
    // construct a vector of vectors to represent an adjacency list
    vector<vector<int>> adjList;

    // Graph Constructor
    Graph(vector<Edge> const &edges, int N)
    {
        // resize the vector to N elements of type vector<int>
        adjList.resize(N);

        // add edges to the undirected graph
        for (auto &edge: edges)
        {
            adjList[edge.src].push_back(edge.dest);
            adjList[edge.dest].push_back(edge.src);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    int N, S;   // Number of nodes in the graph and number of 
    scanf("%d", &N);
    // vector of graph edges as per above diagram
    vector<Edge> edges;
    int a,b;
    for(int i = 0; i < (N-1); i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
        edges.push_back({a, b});
    }
    // create a graph from given edges
    Graph graph(edges, N);

    return 0;
}
```